# mapping characters bomb phase_5

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, gdb, reverse-engineering

Okay guys I know there is a similar question to this already on Stack but I still don't understand how to map the characters to the array table.

This bomb phases takes in a string of length 6. I know the 6 characters that the program uses need to added up to 0x24 line <+53>.

So if I entered something like tttttt which as the ascii value of 116 or 01110100 and if you get the last 4 of the binary it would equal to 4. so 4 * 6 characters is = 0x24 or 36 in decimal.

I'm still really confused as to how to map it. can someone help me solve it. Or show me how to map it.

Thanks

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
   0x0000000000401123 <+0>:     push   %rbx
   0x0000000000401124 <+1>:     mov    %rdi,%rbx
   0x0000000000401127 <+4>:     callq  0x401361 <string_length>
   0x000000000040112c <+9>:     cmp    $0x6,%eax
   0x000000000040112f <+12>:    je     0x401136 <phase_5+19>
   0x0000000000401131 <+14>:    callq  0x4015e4 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401136 <+19>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040113b <+24>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x0000000000401140 <+29>:    movzbl (%rbx,%rax,1),%ecx
   0x0000000000401144 <+33>:    and    $0xf,%ecx
=> 0x0000000000401147 <+36>:    add    0x4025e0(,%rcx,4),%edx
   0x000000000040114e <+43>:    add    $0x1,%rax
   0x0000000000401152 <+47>:    cmp    $0x6,%rax
   0x0000000000401156 <+51>:    jne    0x401140 <phase_5+29>
   0x0000000000401158 <+53>:    cmp    $0x24,%edx
   0x000000000040115b <+56>:    je     0x401162 <phase_5+63>
   0x000000000040115d <+58>:    callq  0x4015e4 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401162 <+63>:    pop    %rbx
   0x0000000000401163 <+64>:    retq

   End of assembler dump.
   (gdb) x/16 0x4025e0
   0x4025e0 <array.3161>:          2       10      6       1
   0x4025f0 <array.3161+16>:       12      16      9       3
   0x402600 <array.3161+32>:       4       7       14      5
   0x402610 <array.3161+48>:       11      8       15      13
```

Comment: The sum needs to be `0x24`, so pick any 6 numbers from the table that add up to `0x24` then for each index pick any ascii character that has the appropriate low bits.

Answer (score -1):

I would also like to know how to find the actual characters